# SpriteKit Swift 2 Trouble writing to plist

Tags: plist

hi can somebody point me in the right direction I'm using the latest Xcode and swift I've managed to surtout copying the plist and reading it but it won't write ? any help much appreciated

```
var NameOfPlist = "Data"

func CopyPlistAndReadContentsToAnArray(NameOfPlist:String)
{

let url = NSURL(string: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0])
let  plistPathInDocument = (url?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(NameOfPlist + ".plist").absoluteString)!

if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(plistPathInDocument)
{
    let plistPathInBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(NameOfPlist, ofType: "plist")!
    do
    {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(plistPathInBundle, toPath: plistPathInDocument)
        let levelPlist =  plistPathInDocument
        MainArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: levelPlist)!
        print("plist copied")
    }
    catch
    {
        print("error copying plist!")
    }
}
else
{
    let levelPlist =  plistPathInDocument
    MainArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: levelPlist)!
    print("PlistInDocOk")
    // print("plst  \(plistPathInDocument)") // = Data/Application/7D6891BB-2EE5-4D1A-8EB5-73B8100F0827/Documents/Data.plist
    // print("This is the MainArray \(MainArray)")
}


}


func SaveToPlist(NameOfPlist:String)
{
let url = NSURL(string: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0])
let  plistPathInDocument = (url?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(NameOfPlist).absoluteString)!
MainArray.writeToFile(plistPathInDocument, atomically: true)
print("Item Added")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i woke early this morning And thought I'm going to crack this I put  this line in the save plist function

`print("plst  \(plistPathInDocument)")`

which showed me that the .plist was missing 
so  i added

`MainArray.writeToFile(plistPathInDocument + ".plist", atomically: true)`

So now its fully working The  whole code hope this helps somebody as i had a hard time finding how to do this in Swift 2

variable to hold plist name so you can swap plists easily

```
  var NameOfPlist = "Data"
```

Function to move plist to docs if its not there and read it

```
func CopyPlistAndReadContentsToAnArray(NameOfPlist:String)
{

let url = NSURL(string: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0])
let  plistPathInDocument = (url?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(NameOfPlist + ".plist").absoluteString)!

if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(plistPathInDocument)
{
    let plistPathInBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(NameOfPlist, ofType: "plist")!
    do
    {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(plistPathInBundle, toPath: plistPathInDocument)
        let levelPlist =  plistPathInDocument
        MainArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: levelPlist)!
        print("plist copied")
    }
    catch
    {
        print("error copying plist!")
    }
}
else
{
    let levelPlist =  plistPathInDocument
    MainArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: levelPlist)!
    print("Plist In Doc Ok")
    print("plst  \(plistPathInDocument)") // = Data/Application/7D6891BB-2EE5-4D1A-8EB5-73B8100F0827/Documents/Data.plist
    // print("This is the MainArray \(MainArray)")
   }


}
```

function to save to plist

```
func SaveToPlist(NameOfPlist:String)
{

let url = NSURL(string: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0])
let  plistPathInDocument = (url?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(NameOfPlist).absoluteString)!
MainArray.writeToFile(plistPathInDocument + ".plist", atomically: true)
print("Item Added")
 print("plst  \(plistPathInDocument)")
```

}